# How do I add an element to right before the last element?

Tags: python, list

I can't figure out how to index `list.insert` if the prompt allows the user to add multiple items to the list. I need to add `"and"` right before the last item of what ever is listed.

```
listToPrint = []
while True:
    newWord = input("Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop adding words) > ")
    if newWord == "":
        break
    else:
        listToPrint.append(newWord)
print(listToPrint)
```

Comment: That places, and, at the beginning.

Comment: @ChristianDean's suggestion is correct, but will cause an error if not a single word is added. You need to add that instruction after the loop, not in it or before it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean @Jack. It places "and" before the last element, which is what you wanted no? Check for yourself.

Comment: I placed what you typed in below the append and it places and at the beginning.

Comment: Don't place it below the append @Jack, place it outside of the loop altogether. It should be at the same indentation level as your last call to print.

Answer (score 1):

As @christiandean suggested in the comments, this is what you're after:

```
listToPrint = []
while True:
    newWord = input("Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop adding words) > ")
    if newWord == "":
        break
    else:
        listToPrint.append(newWord)

listToPrint.insert(len(listToPrint)-1, "and")

print(listToPrint)
```

However, that fails if there's no words entered, so this is safer:

```
listToPrint = []
while True:
    newWord = input("Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop adding words) > ")
    if newWord == "":
        break
    else:
        listToPrint.append(newWord)

if len(listToPrint) > 1:
    listToPrint.insert(len(listToPrint)-1, "and")

print(listToPrint)
```

Output:

```
Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop adding words) > this
Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop adding words) > that
Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop adding words) > more
Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop adding words) > 
['this', 'that', 'and', 'more']
```

Comment: I was creating a list instead of entering each item separate. Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I’m understanding the question correctly. If not, please forgive me. So,[-1] would index the last element of the sequence, I believe. Therefore [-2] would indicate the next to last element.

Comment: Thanks for contributing on StackOverflow - if you write an answer, it's often helpful to provide a code example of what your answer would look like, especially if OP provided code of what they were doing. Also, in this case you're right in pointing out how to index the next to last item in a list with 2 or more items, but that's not exactly what OP is asking, they are asking how to insert in that position.

Comment: You could make this work with something like: `listToPrint[:-1] + ["and"] + listToPrint[-1:]`. Now, I wouldn't necessarily recommend this method as it's less clear then just a call to `list.insert`.

Comment: @ChristianDean Or `listToPrint[-1:-1] = ["and"]`.

Comment: Clever! @KellyBundy that would also work.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, this should done using:

```
listLen = len(listToPrint)
if listLen > 1:
    listToPrint.insert(listLen - 1, "and")
```